# Разные отступы в фотографиях виджета Facebook

Tags: xhtml, html, вёрстка

Посмотрите на скриншот виджета, установленного на сайте, в различных браузерах различные отступы
[image]

Как можно исправить? Это ведь фейсбук не дает доступ к своим стилям, грузит все сам со своих серверов через окно фрейма, может кто знает, как можно изменять их стили, или как другим способом исправить эти отступы, чтобы они были везде одинаковы (должно быть как в ff 3,6).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу судить, этот виджет - некий iframe, содержимое которого генерируется php-скриптом. Логично предположить, что если и меняется там что-то, то только на стороне самого сервера.
Конечно, хотелось бы ошибаться, но навряд ли Facebook разрешит кому-то там менять свои элементы.

**UPD.** 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
Можно поэкспериментировать с параметрами  "width" и "font".

Comment: Да Вы абсолютно правы, залезть в их код нельзя, но ведь на сайте pixel perfect, а выглядит совсем плохо. Может есть какие-то хитрости,которые позволяют переопределять их стили,может надо передать какой-то параметр их серверу. Я конечно увеличиваю высоту iframe для ие7 и 6 через хак (буквы вмещаются, но вот расстояние между кнопкой like и фотками осталось таким же), в убунту все стало на место, но это не успокаивает.

Comment: Можно посмотреть на оф. сайте (ссылка в ответе). Я там, правда, ничего особенно полезного не нашел, но я не особо то и искал.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь VioLet, я по этой ссылке ходил когда получал сам код для виджета. Я проверил через ие7 и фф 3.6 на самом сайте фейсбука, когда генерируете код виджета - отступы разные. Так что это их не доработка (довольно странная).Задал вопрос у них на форуме поддержки может что-то ответят

Comment: @makregistr Да развеж это помощь. Как-то вот и самому интересно стало, как это у них косяк такой. Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, тут, если ответят вам в саппорте.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы исправить этот баг, пришлось парсить виджет через php и curl с фейсбука и выводить на нашем сайте на странице вида some-site/facebook.php, во время парсинга в тело страницы подключается наш файлик со стилями. Потом эта страница грузиться через фрейм в нужное место страницы, функционал виджета не пострадал все нормально работает.